# No mapping exists from object type System.Data.DataRowView?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this code

```
private void cmb_public_manag_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    //DB_Mange.fill_combox_Exchange("[Public_administration_dept]", cmb_public_manag_dept, "dept_id", "dept_name", cmb_public_manag.SelectedValue, "");
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SQL_DB.con_str))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand())
        {
            scm.Connection = con;
            scm.CommandText = "select * from  Public_administration_dept where Public_administration_id=@dept_id";
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept_id",cmb_public_manag.SelectedValue);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adpt.SelectCommand = scm;
            adpt.Fill(dt);

            cmb_public_manag_dept.DisplayMember = dt.Columns["dept_name"].ToString();
            cmb_public_manag_dept.ValueMember = dt.Columns["dept_id"].ToString();
            cmb_public_manag_dept.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

always  showing me this error

> No mapping exists from object type System.Data.DataRowView to a known
>   managed provider native type.
>   this code SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: Wh t do you expect from `dt.Columns["dept_name"].ToString();`? You always get the same back that you pass in, `"dept_name"` in this case.

Comment: On which line you get this exception?

Comment: in this line   adpt.Fill(dt);

Comment: when make trace not arrive to dt.Columns["dept_name"].ToString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the exception is raised at

```
scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept_id",cmb_public_manag.SelectedValue);
```

and that `cmb_public_manag.SelectedValue` is not an `int` but a `DataRowView`. Then use:

```
int dept_id = ((DataRowView) cmb_public_manag.SelectedValue).Row.Field<int>("dept_id");
scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept_id", dept_id );
```

The reason for `cmb_public_manag.SelectedValue` being a `DataRowView` instead of an `int` is    the order of assignment.

Always provide the `DataSource` as the last step since that can cause events in winforms. In these events the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` are not yet assigned.  In this case the code is sitting in the `SelectedIndexChanged` of the `ComboBox` that you are currently assigning the `DataSource`, so the method calls itself. But because you have assigned the `DataSource` first the `ValueMember` is unassigned and the whole object is returned from `SelectedValue`.

So instead use this:

```
cmb_public_manag_dept.SelectedIndexChanged -= cmb_public_manag_SelectedIndexChanged;
cmb_public_manag_dept.DisplayMember = "dept_name";
cmb_public_manag_dept.ValueMember = "dept_id";
cmb_public_manag_dept.DataSource = dt;
cmb_public_manag_dept.SelectedIndexChanged += cmb_public_manag_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Note that you should also unsubscribe from this event when you change the datasource in it.

Also note that i've changed `dt.Columns["dept_name"].ToString()` to simply `"dept_name"` which is the same.

Comment: NOt Arrive to  cmb_public_manag_dept.DataSource = dt;
when making trace 
update the code but the same error

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.
in the new line<br>
int dept_id = ((DataRowView) cmb_public_manag.SelectedValue).Row.Field<int>("dept_id");

Comment: @eng.YahiaGalal: You haven't got it. You either have to use one of both solutions. You don't have to cast it to `DataRowView` if you change the order as suggested in my `instead use this: ..`. I have also shown how to unsubscribe from the event during databinding.

Comment: Run With This Code :D :D 
 scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept_id",Convert.ToInt32(cmb_public_manag .SelectedValue));
thx 
to try with me (Y)